# Not encountering end of file (eof) in C

Tags: c, eof, cs50

I am trying to run the code. All the images are coming fine as per specification excluding the last one.

The first four bytes (B) repeating are as follows :

```
b8 97 98 c5
```

The end of file is not encountered as a result the last image is found corrupted.

EDIT:

1. It is already mentioned that there are 50 images in the file.
2. You can get the raw file from : http://cdn.cs50.net/2017/fall/psets/4/recover/card.raw

The original code is as follows :

```
// Recovers lost images (.jpeg) in a memory card

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define buffsize 10

// Function to check whether jpeg or not
int check_jpeg(unsigned char *argv) {
    unsigned int v1 = (int)argv[0];
    unsigned int v2 = (int)argv[1];
    unsigned int v3 = (int)argv[2];
    unsigned int v4 = (int)argv[3];
    if (v1 == 0xff && v2 == 0xd8 && v3 == 0xff) {
        switch (v4) {
          case 0xe0:
          case 0xe1:
          case 0xe2:
          case 0xe3:
          case 0xe4:
          case 0xe5:
          case 0xe6:
          case 0xe7:
          case 0xe9:
          case 0xea:
          case 0xeb:
          case 0xec:
          case 0xed:
          case 0xee:
          case 0xef:
            return 1;
            break;
          default:
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Cautioning the user for wrong usage
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./recover file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Opens the .raw file to begin inspection
    FILE *camera = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    // Checks the validity of the opened file
    if (camera == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file: %s\n",argv[1]);
        return 2;
    }

    int counter = 0; // Declaring and Initialising the counter
    int online = 0; // To know whether image is being written

    char *filename = (char*)malloc(buffsize);
    FILE *outptr;

    while (1) {
        unsigned char *image = malloc(512);
        if (image == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error creating pointer \n");
            return 200;
        }
        fread(image, 512, 1, camera);
        if (image != NULL) {
            int flag = check_jpeg(image);
            if (counter == 50) {
                printf("%x %x %x %x\n", image[0], image[1], image[2], image[3]);
            }
            if (flag == 1) {
                if (counter != 0) {
                    fclose(outptr);
                }
                counter++;

                // Creating the output file pointer
                snprintf(filename, buffsize - 1, "%03i.jpg", counter);
                outptr = fopen(filename, "w");
                if (outptr == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file: %s\n", filename);
                    return 201;
                }

                // Writing to the file
                fwrite(image, 512, 1, outptr);
                online = 1;
            } else
            if (flag == 0 && online == 1) {
                fwrite(image, 512, 1, outptr); // Continue writing to the output file
            }
            free(image);
        } else {
            fclose(camera);
            fclose(outptr);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any checks for `eof` in this code. Check the return value of `fread()`.

Comment: I don't see the need for allocating `image` dynamically. It could as easily be an array instead. And you never check what [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) and [`fwrite`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) ***returns***. Which is very important because both can fail, and especially important to check what `fread` returns since it will tell you if end-of-file have been reached.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure a [mcve] about your problem would be a **lot** shorter.

Comment: I haven't even checked the code, I just observe that raw and jpeg are vastly different formats.

Comment: @visibleman this is a coding assignment, I *guess* the "raw" file should be some hypothetical disk contents after deleting images and your job is to detect and recover those. -- anyways, for a [mcve], you're expected to create a simple example program that just contains the problem in question (so images are irrelevant here).

Comment: Checking `image != NULL` after calling `fread` is redundant as `fread` doesn't change the value of `image`

Comment: As I am new to StackOverlow, apologies for not providing the Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`fread`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/) wont set the pointer (or is at least not guaranteed to) to NULL on failed read. In fact I think it is supposed to leave the pointer unchanged. `fread` will however return the number of bytes read, so you could change:

```
   fread(image, 512, 1, camera);
   if (image != NULL)
```

to

```
   int bytesread=fread(image, 1, 512, camera);
   if (bytesread!= 512)
```

Comment: The arguments to `fread` should be swapped: `int bytesread = fread(image, 1, 512, camera);`

Comment: @Pritthijit Nath,  I didn't see it until later, but yes, your suggested edit would also have worked.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- you do not check how much data `fread` successfully reads. At end of file, `fread` returns `0`, otherwise `fread` returns the number of blocks successfully read into the destination array. To keep track of bytes read, pass `1` as the block size and `512` as the number of *blocks*.
- there is no real need to allocate the filename and the input/output buffers, local arrays are fine for your purpose.
- the files should be open in binary mode: `FILE *camera = fopen(argv[1], "rb");`
- the second argument to `snprintf` should be the buffer size, not the maximum number of characters to write: `snprintf(filename, buffsize, "%03i.jpg", counter);`

Answer (score 0):

You might be tempted to do the following:

```
while (!feof(camera)) {
```

However, this works only in the case of there being no other errors reading the file, and even then always results in there being one additional read of the file (the one that triggers the EOF condition). That last read may return bad or point to stale data and so needs to be handled as per @chqrlie's answer and [this previous question about feof()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Bottom line:
Check the number of bytes read, if it less than requested then use `ferror()` and `feof()` to isolate the cause so you can respond accordingly.

Comment: No, this is incorrect. `feof()` should only be used after an unsuccessful attempt to read contents from the file, to distinguish end of file from read error.

Comment: @chqrlie 'feof()' merely checks the stream state. Which does indeed only get updated after an unsuccessful read. What is the danger in using it every iteration?

Comment: It is the wrong tool for the job: if `fread` fails, the code should not use the contents of the buffer and exit the loop. Testing `feof()` before this will not give the appropriate info. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: Ok, valid point. Thank you for correcting a couple decades of bad programming habits. I shall edit my post accordingly to state it is a bad idea

Comment: @Spoonless: `feof` won't return true until *after* you try to read past the end of the file, so you'll wind up looping once too often (which, depending on the algorithm, can result in Bad Things).  Always check the result of the input operation (`fscanf`, `fgets`, `fread`, etc.), and if they indicate a failure, *then* use `feof` to see if you've hit EOF or if some other error occurred.

Comment: @John Bode. Isn't that exactly what I said in the text of my answer?

Comment: @Spoonless: I was responding to your comment "what is the danger in using it every iteration?"  Suppose the file is a record of credits and debits against a bank account.  Looping once too often would mean the last transaction gets processed twice, resulting in an incorrect balance.  Customers tend to yell when that happens.